# How to save EF in a cache layer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, enterprise-library

I'm using Entity Framework.

I save the object in an MS_library cache manager.

However I now encounter a problem: when I retreieve this object from the cache

its ContextObj is already disposed.

How can I fix this without mapping each entity to my model object?

```
public partial class MaMDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public MaMDBEntities()
        : base("name=MaMDBEntities")
    {

        ObjectContext.
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<App> Apps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AppsData> AppsDatas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Browser> Browsers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BrowserVersion> BrowserVersions { get; set; }
    public DbSet<BrowserVerToCriteria> BrowserVerToCriterias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CommonConfig> CommonConfigs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Criterion> Criteria { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CTID> CTIDS { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DatabaseLastUpdate> DatabaseLastUpdates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MamConfiguration> MamConfigurations { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MamConfigurationCTID> MamConfigurationCTIDs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MamConfigurationStatus> MamConfigurationStatuses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pair> Pairs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SettingsServicesConfig> SettingsServicesConfigs { get; set; }
    public DbSet<sysdiagram> sysdiagrams { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CtidPgPastExistence> CtidPgPastExistences { get; set; }

    public virtual ObjectResult<usp_AppsData_GetAll_Result> usp_AppsData_GetAll()
    {
        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_AppsData_GetAll_Result>("usp_AppsData_GetAll");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either load the navigational properties that you try to access with include() or turn off the ProxyObjectCreation in the object context properties.

```
Context.SomeCollection.Include("NavigationalProperty")
```

or

```
Context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

If you decide to turn off the proxy creation you must retest all of your queries that are using lazy loading, because there will be silent bugs introduced in your solution.

Comment: var data = (from x in Context.SomeCollection.Include("NavigationalProperty")
select x).ToList()

Comment: but my hirarchy has maney bested entities. not sure If that't the solution

Comment: You will have many includes. Otherwise you have to keep the context alive which is not a smart thing to do(multithreading and concurrency).

Comment: how do I do eager loading + detaching afterwards?

Comment: You have to materialize the navigational properties right after retrieving from the context.
Ex. instance.NavigationalPropertyList.ToList()..

Comment: I have many nested entities (A->B's->C's->D's). Is there any elegant syntax for that?

Comment: Out of the box you have to do includes. No elegant way to do it. It is one of the pitfalls of using EF.

Comment: thanks. I was thinking of verifying the ObjectContext has been disposed and if so- attaching it to a new one. But how do I check if it has been disposed

Comment: btw, will `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` load the whole objects tree?

Comment: Nope, ProxyCreationEnabled = false disables the lazy loading. You have to take care of loading what you need in the linq query (with include)

Comment: You don't need to check if the context is disabled it is a bad practice. Load what you need in the query.